# Subprocess call fails

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

```
import shlex,subprocess,os
cmd = "/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/swriter --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir ~/Downloads ~/Downloads/HS303.xlsx"
#This works
os.popen(cmd)
#This doesnot work
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Subprocess calls are not working. This was done in Mac OSX.
Any idea as to why this is happening ?

Comment: Please clarify "are not working". Do any subprocess calls work? What result do you get, an exception?

Comment: I did check_output but it prints ' ', answer posted below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem is the ~/Downloads path. the ~ is expanded by the shell environment which wasn't enabled when you called `subprocess.call`. Below is a simplified demonstration of the problem:

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess, os, os.path
>>> cmd = "ls ~/Downloads"
>>> print os.popen(cmd).read()
ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso
ubuntu-11.04-server-i386.iso

>>> print subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd))
ls: cannot access ~/Downloads: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '~/Downloads']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

**The solutions**

There are two solutions you could use, either expand the ~ in python using `os.path.expanduser` or call `subprocess.call`/`subprocess.check_output` with argument `shell=True`. I prefer to use `check_output` over `call` because it returns any output that might have been produced by the command. Either solution below should solve your problem.

```
import shlex, subprocess, os, os.path
cmd = 'ls ' + os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
print subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd))

cmd = 'ls ~/Downloads'
print subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```