# Subprocess run/call not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

I want to use the "[raster2pgsql](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html)" utility in my Python code. When I use it in a Linux terminal, it works fine. This is the command:

```
$ raster2pgsql -a "/mnt/c/Users/Jan/path/to/raster/dem.tiff" test_schema.raster2 | psql -h localhost -d pisl -U pisl
```

Then I use subprocess.run (I have also tried subprocess.call) to use this same tool in my Python code. This is my code:

```
from subprocess import run
command = ["raster2pgsql", "-a", '"' + file_name + '"', self.schema_name +  "." + identifier, "|", "psql", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432", "-d", self.dbname]
run(command)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to read raster file: "/mnt/c/Users/Jan/path/to/raster/dem.tiff"
```

Printing `command` gives this which I think is correct (equivalent to what worked in the terminal):

```
['raster2pgsql', '-a', '"/mnt/c/Users/Jan/path/to/raster/dem.tiff"', 'test_schema.raster2', '|', 'psql', '-h', 'localhost', '-p', '5432', '-d', 'pisl']
```

I have double checked that the path to the raster file is correct, tried single quotes, double quotes but nothing helps. I have looked at a number of similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742494/subprocess-call-fails), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550667/subprocess-call-not-working) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323798/python3-subprocess-call-not-working) ) but did not find anything helpful.

I use Python 3.5 and Linux Bash Shell in Windows 10.

**Question**: What is wrong with the way I use subprocess?

Comment: why are you quoting the filename at all?

Comment: because it doesn't recognize the filename when I don't. When I remove the quotes it considers  "test_schema.raster2" to be the filename.

Comment: I've provided an alternate method with 2 commands piped together. Please test that. report error accurately if any. I doubt that the quotes are the issue, since the shell removes them on the working command you performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 issues here:

- no need to extra-quote the filename. It's passed to the system literally and since there's no file called `"/tmp/something"` the command fails.
- second, to be able to pass a pipe, you need `shell=True`

so quickfix:

```
command = ["raster2pgsql", "-a", file_name, self.schema_name +  "." + identifier, "|", "psql", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432", "-d", self.dbname]
run(command,shell=True)
```

or using a command string (because `shell=True` is picky with argument list):

```
command = "raster2pgsql -a "+ file_name + " " + self.schema_name +  "." + identifier + " | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d" + self.dbname
run(command,shell=True)
```

(ugly, isn't it?)

It's *much* better to run 2 processes without `shell=True` and pipe them together using python, more portable & secure (not sure how `shell=True` reacts with an argument list on Linux):

```
from subprocess import *
command1 = ["raster2pgsql", "-a", file_name, self.schema_name +  "." + identifier]
p = Popen(command1,stdout=PIPE)
command2 = ["psql", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "5432", "-d", self.dbname]
run(command2,stdin=p.stdout)
```

The first `Popen` object created writes its output to a pipe (thanks to `stdout=PIPE` argument). The `run` function can take an input as a pipe too (thanks to `stdin=p.stout)`. It consumes the output of the first command, creating a native piped chain of commands, without the need of the shell (and the caveats of quoting, spaces, special character interpretation and such...)

Comment: Thanks the for the explaination. I was trying to ask a py 3 script to run a py 2 script and I use `process = subprocess.run(['py', '-2', os.path.basename(latest_file)])` but for some reason it didn't run. I accidentally came this and by adding `shell=True` in a different line, it works. Any chance you know why it works? Thank you so much!

Comment: you mean that `subprocess.run(['py', '-2', os.path.basename(latest_file)],shell=True)` runs and without shell=True it doesn't? that may well be another question to ask.

Comment: Oh quite the contrary. In one line it didnt' work. But in the format you proposed as a "dirty": `command = ['py', '-2', os.path.basename(latest_file)] subprocess.run(command, shell=True)`it works.

Comment: @Donald Li In my case if I use a Shell=True I have to use a string and not a list...